# Tell FutureTask It Is Done With Nested Async Callback

Tags: java, asynchronous

Sorry if this is a duplicate or a dumb question -- I tried a lot sleuthing and can't find exactly what I'm looking for, though I know this is a simple concept.

I have the following:

```java
 return new FutureTask<>(() -> {
      processFile(param1, param2, <optional callback>)
    });
```

`processFile` is a method from a library I'm using, which executes asynchronously in its own thread, and calls the `<optional callback>` if supplied when it's complete.

I want a way to be able to not mark the surrounding `FutureTask` as `done` until the nested async task `processFile` is done. What's the best way to do this?

A couple options I thought of:

1. I could implement my own `Future` instead,  make a `done` boolean field in the Future, override isDone to return the boolean value, and only mark `done` as true from the `processFile` callback.
2. Use a `CountdownLatch` in the `FutureTask` and `await` that until the callback sets it to zero.

I think either of those would work, but I'm not sure that's the most semantically or logically correct way to go about this.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So to understand the question correctly: Method `processFile(...)` being async means that it starts a separate thread in which the actual work is done?

Comment: Yes that's correct, and it does not return anything.

Comment: In this case, I would recommend to not additionally wrap those tasks in a `FutureTask`. We could instead add the data processed to, for example, some `List` or `Map`.

Comment: Hmm, I would agree and that's certainly cleaner but the issue is that the API I must follow requires me to supply a task that implements both a `cancel` and `run`, and the `processFile` method (which I can't change -- it's a third party API), returns nothing so it seems there's no way to manage that task without wrapping it in a `FutureTask`?

Comment: We cannot implement `cancel()` in a meaningful way anyway since the actual work is done in another thread, and threads cannot be "stopped" if the code executed on the thread does not check for cancelation. On top of this: to cancel a thread, we need a handle TO that thread, which we do not have.